# Polishing my Pig Latin translator (Code) (Java)

Tags: java

my assignment here was to create a pig latin translator using recursion, that could translate sentences.  The rules were as follows:

1. If there are no vowels in englishWord, then pigLatinWord is just englishWord + "ay". (There   are ten vowels: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u', and their uppercase counterparts. ‘y’ is not considered to be a vowel for the purposes of this assignment, i.e. my becomes myay, why becomes whyay, etc.)
2. Else, if englishWord begins with a vowel, then pigLatinWord is just englishWord + "yay".
3. Otherwise (if englishWord has a vowel in it and yet doesn't start with a vowel), then pigLatinWord is end + start + "ay", where end and start are defined as follows: 
   -

Let start be all of englishWord up to (but not including) its first vowel.
Let end be all of englishWord from its first vowel on.
But, if englishWord is capitalized, then capitalize end and "uncapitalize" start.

Here's my code so far (sorry about the weird formatting, my comments got messed up):

```
    /*Recursively Translate a String (without punctuation or numerical characters) to Pig Latin*/


//prep the string for translation and submit it to be translated
public static String translate(String finished) {
    finished.trim();        //Trim the String of whitespace at the front and end
    finished += " ";        //Because of the recursive method I use, the string must have a
                            //space at the end
    finished = translateSentence(finished); //recursively translate the string
    finished.trim();    //trim the whitespace added earlier
    return finished;    //Return the string
}


//recursively submits each word in the string to the translator, then 
//returns the translated sentence
private static String translateSentence(String finished) {

if (finished.length() == 0) {   //the base condition is met when each word in the string
   return finished; //has been sent to the translator (string is empty)
    }
    else {
    return (translateWord(finished.substring(0, finished.indexOf(' ') )) + " "
        + translateSentence(finished.substring(finished.indexOf(' ') + 1)));        
    }
}
/*If the base condition is not met, the method returns the first word of the string
 * (translated) and a space, then submits the rest of the 
 * string back to the method.  The first word is defined as the beginning 
 * of the string up until the first space. The rest of the string
 * starts one character after the space.   */



//Checks the submitted word for vowels and vowel placement, and translates accordingly

    private static String translateWord(String stringA) {
    if (stringA.indexOf('a') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('e') == -1           //Checks for presence of any vowels
    && stringA.indexOf('i') == -1       //if no vowels are found
    && stringA.indexOf('o') == -1       //the word + ay is returned
    && stringA.indexOf('u') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('A') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('E') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('I') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('O') == -1
    && stringA.indexOf('U') == -1) {
        return stringA + "ay";
    }       
    if (stringA.charAt(0) == 'a'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'e' //checks if there is a vowel at the start
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'i'//of the string. if there is a vowel
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'o'    //it returns the word + yay
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'u'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'A'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'E'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'I'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'O'
    ||  stringA.charAt(0) == 'U') {
        return stringA + "yay";
    }       
/* if the word has a vowel that isn't at the start, the part of the string


* before the first vowel is moved to the end of the vowel, and "ay" is added.


* However, if the first character in the word is capitalized, the first vowel becomes


* uppercase and the former first character in the word becomes lowercase */
    else {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(stringA.charAt(0))) {
            return Character.toUpperCase(stringA.charAt(firstVowel(stringA, 0))) 
            + stringA.substring(firstVowel(stringA, 0) + 1, stringA.length())
            + Character.toLowerCase(stringA.charAt(0))
            + stringA.substring(1, firstVowel(stringA, 0)) + "ay";
        }
        else {
        return stringA.substring(firstVowel(stringA, 0), stringA.length()) 
        + stringA.substring(0, firstVowel(stringA, 0)) + "ay";
        }
    }
}



//Recursively determines the index number of the first vowel in a given word
//0 must always be submitted as int x
public static int firstVowel(String stringA, int x) {
    if (x > stringA.length() - 1) {     //if the index number becomes greater than the length
        return -1;      //of the string, -1 (no vowels) is returned
    }
    if (stringA.charAt(x) == 'a' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'e'     //the base condition is met when the character
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'i'     //at the current index number is a vowel
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'o'     //and the index number is returned
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'u' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'A' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'E' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'I' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'O' 
        || stringA.charAt(x) == 'U') {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        return firstVowel(stringA, x + 1);  //otherwise, the string and the index number
    }                                       // + 1 are submitted back to the method
}
```

This gives me the desired output ("Why hello there" becomes "Whyay ellohay erethay")
but right now it can't handle punctuation.  Basically what I'm looking for are any tips or help getting my code to handle punctuation, or any ways to improve my code (still using recursion) in general.

Comment: One improvement is to put all your vowels in a string constant and use `contains()` to check if a character is a vowel. Furthermore, `firstVowel(stringA, 0)` can be extracted into a local variable, which would further improve readability.

Comment: Can you clarify the part about the contains() method? I don't really understand how I would relate the string constant, contains(), and the string I'm checking.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant something like this: `private static final String VOWELS = "aeiouAEIOU";`, and then when you're checking for vowels, you do `private static boolean isVowel( char ch ) { return VOWELS.contains( String.valueOf( ch ) ); }`. It's a lot easier to read than a big `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cedric give a good suggestion to make use of Regex in performing the processing.

Here I give some other directions.

First I believe you can have better reuse of your `firstVowel` method.

Your `translateWord` can be greatly simplified as (I skip your upper-case handling to make it easier to understand):

```
private static String translateWord(String s) {
    int firstVowelIndex = firstVowel(s);
    if (firstVowel < 0) { // no Vowel
        return s + "ay";
    } else if (firstVowel == 0) {  // start with Vowel
        return s + "yay";
    } else {
        return s.substring(firstVowelIndex) + s.substring(0, firstVowelIndex) + "ay";
    }
}
```

There are something to simplify in your `firstVowel()` too.

First the comparison of Vowel can be simplified.  One way is to use regex.  Another way is by using a Set:

assume you have something like this:

```
static Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(
        Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'));
```

Then your vowel checking can be changed from a long if statement to something like:

```
if (vowels.contains(c)) {...}
```

Second, you may be intentionally writing firstVowel() in a recursive manner for practice.  However, it seems to me that the method is much easier to read if it is wrote in form of a loop:

```
private static int firstVowel(String s) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i ) {
        if (isVowel(s.charAt(i)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

I believe simply these two changes can almost half your code, in a more readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex to match your words. The regex [a-zA-Z]+ will match any simultaneous sequence of letters. I will leave it as an exercise to you as to how to use regexes in java, but it is not too hard.

Basically take your string, find the next match. Store the position of the last character of the word in the original string. Process that word, and then find the next match. Now take the substring between the last character of the previous match and the first character of the current match, and output it as it is, without any processing.

Example: Suppose I have the string "Hello, world!"

- The first match would be "Hello" starting at position 0 and ending at position 4 (inclusive).
- Process that and output "Ellohay"
- Find the next match which would be "world" starting at position 7 and ending at position 11
- Output the substring between the last character of the previous match, and the first character of the current match. This would mean from position 5 to position 6, which gives the string ", "
- process the current match and output it. This would output "orldway"
- Try to find the next match. No matches are now found
- output the rest of the string without any processing. This means from position 12 to the end of the string. This gives the substring "!"

In this way the process would transform "Hello, world!" to "Ellohay, orldway!"

Hope this helps